# Long value get rounded in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a grid view whose data is based on a `long` value as the key and need that key for doing other operations (to find the record). The value is getting rounded up in the view when passed to an action:

```
ActionLink("some action", "some action", new{ key = "#=key#"}); // #= # is Kendo syntax
```

For example:

```
636280844960803997 is rounded to
636280844960804000
```

So what's the fix considering that I cannot add any attribute on that property in my model.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that JavaScript supports only 53-bit integers, which would make the largest supported integer to be 9007199254740991. Your key is larger than that. You can take a look at `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

The solution to this problem is to use string representations of your key on the client side. A good example of this is the Twitter API, where they return both an integer and a string: `{"id": 10765432100123456789, "id_str": "10765432100123456789", ...}`. There is a good article about it here: http://2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html

If you are using ASP.NET MVC I would recommend that you add another property to your model classes, which returns a `ToString()` version of your key. That way you can use the string version in JavaScript, while taking advantage of the numeric values within your database or server-side code. Here's an example

```
public class Item
    {
        public Item()
        {
            // ... your constructor code here ...
        }

        // Your long integer key
        public Int64 ItemId { get; set; }

        // The string version of your key
        public string ItemIdString
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ItemId.ToString();
            }
        }

        // The rest of your fields
        // ...
}
```

Then you can use `ItemIdString`, when you bind your Kendo grid or anything else on the client side.

If you cannot modify the original class then I'd recommend that you create a subclass that inherits from the original one and add the `ItemIdString` property to that. Then just use the subclass to bind your grid.

Answer (score 0):

You can used string instead of int in key field if possible so value can not be rounded

Comment: your key field is int right? means model value of key is int